# Converting std::map to Objective-C NSMutableArray elements

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I want to convert values of std::map to NSMutableArray element.
My CPP code is passing std::map (with one int and std::string) to an Objective-C function using interface function.

But i am not able to convert this std::map to NSMutableArray.

```
CPP Code:
------------------------------------------------------------------    
typedef std::map<int, std::string> TemList;
temList temList;
temList[10]="an element";
temList[23]="another element";
temList[545]="last";

passing this map to an objective-c code using interface function. 

Objective-c Code
------------------------------------------------------------------  
- (void) testListUpdate:(const TemList&) pList
{
    NSMutableArray *mArray = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    

    for (TemList::const_iterator ii = pList.begin(); ii != pList.end(); ++ii)
    {
        ListItem item = [[ListItem alloc] init]
        
        // PROBLEM **** I am Not able to convert this ******
        item.name = ii->second.c_str();
        item.mId = (int) ii->first;
    
        [mArray addObject:item];
    
        //printf("OBJC Value[%s]: Key[%d]\n", ii->second.c_str(), ii->first);
    }
}

// Interface function implementation 
void interfaceListUpdate(void *self, const TemList& pList)
{
    printf("ObjectiveC Interface Function size[%d]\n", pList.size());
    [(id) self testListUpdate:pList];
}

// Using this struct as Array item
@interface ListItem : NSObject
{
    NSString *name;
    int mId;
}

@end
```

Also i want to use `mArray` for displaying table view rows.
How should i do it.

Comment: What does c_str() return?  And what should item.name be (what is it's class)?

Comment: `std::string::c_str()` returns a plain C character array of the string represented by the C++ `string` object (since the internal storage of `std::string` is opaque)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithCString:cppString.c_str() 
                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

or whatever `NSStringEncoding` works for your particular content!

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert your std::string to a NSString. Dont know the exact std::string methods to use but you should do something like this:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:ii->second.c_str() length:ii->second.length()]
```